# Servicestack redis client: setting a key with timespan expiration fails using

Tags: redis, set, servicestack, timespan, ttl

The following sample fails when setting a key with timespan expiration.
When setting the expiration as a datetime, it passes. What am I doing wrong?

```
            using (var redisClient = new RedisClient(cacheHost[0]))
            {
                redisClient.Set<string>("mykey", "myVal", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90)); // fails,exception {"No more data, sPort: 59862, LastCommand: "}
                redisClient.Set<string>("mykey", "session",DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(90)); // OK
                Console.WriteLine(redisClient.Get<string>("mykey"));
            }
```

I am using ServiceStack 4.0.42 and redis 2.6.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the recommendation on Redis is that you [shouldn't use Redis 2.6](http://redis.io/download) so I'd first recommend upgrading redis-server.

The [documentation for SET](http://redis.io/commands/set) command suggests that 2.6.12+ supports the necessary SET options required for expiring values in time, but potentially 2.6.14 still has incomplete support given this works without issue on my local 2.8.4 redis-server.

Comment: thanks mate, I'll try to update. Do ServiceStack Dll's version needs to be matched to redis version? for example, if I have the old free version of ServiceStack 3.0, will it work with the latest version of redis?

Comment: @user2492936 yeah it will work with the latest version of Redis since Redis maintains strong backwards compatibility